# C++ overload [] to access subvector using template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, operator-overloading

I want to overload the [] vector operator to easily create a temporary subvector.

I thought it would be something like the code shown below. However, when I try to compile I get the error:

> error: "operator[]" must be a member function

which [] is a member of vectors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std

template <class T, int a, int b>
T& operator[](int a, int b)
{
    vector<class T> subvector;
    copy ( T.begin() + min(a, b), v1.begin() + max(a, b) + 1, back_inserter(subvector) );

    if (a > b) {reverse(subvector.begin(), subvector.end());};
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message in unclear ? And don't try to "replace" `std::vector::operator[]` (you can't)

Comment: why are `a` and `b` both non-type template parameters and regular parameters?  What type is this supposed to be part of?  Why are you returning a reference to a local?  Why does `operator[]` have two parameters?

Comment: If you want to get really [creative](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator), you can make `auto subVec = vec <from> a <to> b;` work, but please don't.

Answer (score 2):

While some operators like `operator+` and `operator>>` can exist as standalone functions that take some specific number of arguments, `operator[]` cannot. It must be a member function of a class.

What you're attempting to achieve cannot be done either, because `operator[]` can only take one argument.

Just use a function:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> make_sub_vector(std::vector<T> const& v, int begin, int end) {
    assert(begin < end); // Either this, or you swap them 
                         // if this condition is not met.
                         // I'm asserting because I don't know 
                         // what to do when they're equal.
    return std::vector<T>(v.begin() + begin, v.begin() + end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

13.5.5 Subscripting

1 **operator[] shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter**. It implements the subscripting

syntax
postfix-expression [ expression ]

or

postfix-expression [ braced-init-list ]

Thus, a subscripting expression x[y] is interpreted as `x.operator[](y)` for a class object x of type
T if `T::operator[](T1)` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3.3).